# Getting a Quicktime Movie to Stream Instead of Download

Tags: macos, firefox, streaming, quicktime, amazon-s3

In the past, I've placed Quicktime movies on Amazon S3, and when a user loads the file's in Firefox (on OS X), the movie starts playing immediately, doing that pseudo streaming quicktime thing where the movie downloads as it plays.  These files were in the range of 18MB - 22MB.

More recently, I created a larger Quicktime movie (about 80MB) and uploaded it to Amazon S3, and when I load the file in Firefox the big blue quicktime Q just sits there as the file loads.  No player chrome comes up.  When I view my older movies, the chrome still comes up as the movie downloads so I'm pretty sure it's not a browser change.

I vaguely recall there's some way to make have the quicktime file tell the player chrome come up while the movie downloads, but can't remember how.  It's also possible I'm making this up.

Does anyone here know how much control you have over this behavior?

(not posting links to the movies, as they're large and I'd rather not have everyone in the SuperUser community hitting them at the same time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the feature I'm looking for is called "Fast Start", outline in this [knowledge base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2438).

Quicktime's `File -> Export` command (not Save As) has the settings I was looking for.